# How to create a custom log4j2 appender that can write structred data?

Tags: log4j2

Since log4j 1.x is [end of life](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html), I want to build my appender in [Log4j2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) but there is not enough resources nor examples on the net. Additionally, being able to combine it with [Messages](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/messages.html) and [custom log levels](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customloglevels.html) would be great.

Something like this:

```java
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();
logger.log(ACCESS_LOG, new AccessLogMessage("DateTime", "User", "IP", "Data"));
...
try {
   ...
}
catch(ArithmeticException ex) {
   logger.log(EXCEPTION, new ExceptionMessage(ex));
}
```

A simple custom appender that would write logs to console would be enough for me to get started.

PS: My ultimate goal is to convert the structered log data to json format and send it to my REST service.

Answer (score 2):

An appender that writes to the console already exists. It is called the [ConsoleAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#ConsoleAppender). If you want to format the data in some special way then you would create a custom Layout to do that.

Log4j provides many examples of Layouts. The most common use case is to extend AbstractStringLayout and implement the toSerializable method.